# GSAP & ReactJs. Console warnings: GSAP target undefined not found. & GSAP target not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I tried to make a simplified version of what I experienced in another project with using GSAP. Essentially I get 2 warning in the console.

> GSAP target undefined not found.

> GSAP target  not found.

I tried to make a modal that it will render if the state is equal to true. Else it will return null.

I believe my issue is due to returning null. But I don't know how to do this another way.

I experimented with the kill() option in gsap, but I had no luck with it. Here is the reference from the docs that I read. [Gsap Docs about Cleanup](https://greensock.com/react#cleaning-up)

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import gsap from "gsap";

export default function TestGsap(props) {
  const box = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.from(box.current, {
      y: "500",
      ease: "expo",
      duration: 2,
    });
  });

  if (props.toggleModal === true) {
    return (
      <div>
        <section
          ref={box}
          style={{ width: "10rem", height: "10rem", backgroundColor: "red" }}
        >
          <p>Hello, I am a red box.</p>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: initializate GSAP after you render element in DOM

Comment: You initialize GSAP after your render your elements in the DOM by including an empty array as the second parameter of your `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this also on Greensock forums.
Thanks to OSUblake an Admin over at Greensock, he was able to solve my issue. To help others here's what he said.

> Your effect is running every time the props changes, so you're going to create a new animation every time, so of course the target will not be found if it's not rendered. You would need to do something like this.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (props.toggleModal) {
    gsap.from(box.current, {
      ...
    });
  }
}, [props.toggleModal])
```

You can import useLayoutEffect from react.

> Please check out our React Guide for more information.
> https://greensock.com/react/